# What is the background to inequality $|e^{i \alpha\cdot\beta}-1|\leq L |\alpha||\beta|$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

$\alpha=(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n)$, $\beta=(y_1,y_2,\dotsc,y_n)\in\Bbb R^n$, $\alpha \cdot\beta=x_1y_1+x_2y_2+\dotsb+x_ny_n$.

$|\alpha|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\dotsb+x_n^2} $, $|\beta|=\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2+\dotsb+y_n^2}, $

Show that : there exists a constant $L\gt 0$ such that
$$|e^{i \alpha\cdot\beta}-1|\leq L |\alpha||\beta|$$
for all $\alpha,\beta$

---

I don't know where to start

**The question produces background . What is the background?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for $t\in\mathbb{R}$
$$|e^{it}-1|^2=(cos(t)-1)^2+\sin(t)^2=2-2\cos(t)<2|t|^2$$
so $|e^{it}-1|\leq\sqrt{2}|t|$ for all $t$.
Now for $t=\alpha\cdot\beta$ we have that
$$|e^{i\alpha\beta}-1|\leq\sqrt{2}|\alpha\cdot\beta|$$
and using the famous Cauhcy-Schwarz inequality $|\alpha\cdot\beta|\leq|\alpha|\cdot|\beta|$ we get the desired estimate.

Comment: You can get a tighter bound by using MVT or $|\sin x|\leq |x|$ from your work by using the cosine double angle identity.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh yeah, sure! I just used a quick "overkill", of course there are better estimates, I think that the optimal value must be 1, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Hint}$: First prove that

$$|e^{ix}-e^{iy}|\leq L|x-y|$$

for $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$

Answer (score 2):

$e^{\,i\, \alpha \cdot \beta}$ is always less than $2$, whatever is $\alpha \cdot \beta=|\alpha| \, |\beta|\, \cos \theta$.
So we have to consider the case in which $\alpha \cdot \beta$ is small.

[image: mod_(1-exp)]

Since the arc $\alpha \cdot \beta$ is comprised between $\pm |\alpha|\,|\beta|$, then the chord $|e^{\,i\, \alpha \cdot \beta}|$ is not greater that the chord $|e^{|\alpha| \, |\beta|}|$, which in turn is less then the arc $|\alpha| \, |\beta|$, which remains true also when the arc equals $\pi$.

> Thus $L=1$